# Me dice que no está definido pero en realidad lo está

Tags: javascript

Este es mi array de objetos. Es que va todo a la perfección menos cuando llega al último elemento, cuando llega a **Bell** me dice:

> console.log(`Hi my name is ${escritoras[4].nombre}, my fish name is ${escritoras[4].apellido}. I am ${escritoras[4].edad} years old a and working in: ${escritoras[4].profesion}, I am live ? : ${escritoras[4].viva}.`)
> ^
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'nombre' of undefined

```
m var escritoras = [
  {
    nombre: 'Virginia',
    apellido: 'Woolf',
    profesion: 'escritora',
    edad: 59,
    viva: false
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Zadie',
    apellido: 'Smith',
    profesion: 'escritora',
    edad: 41,
    viva: true
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Jane',
    apellido: 'Austen',
    profesion: 'escritora',
    edad: 41,
    viva: false
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Bell',
    apellido: 'Hooks',
    profesion: 'escritora',
    edad: 64,
    viva: true
  }
];
console.log(`Hi my name is ${escritoras[0].nombre}, my fish name is ${escritoras[0].apellido}. I am ${escritoras[0].edad} years old a and working in: ${escritoras[0].profesion}, I am live ? : ${escritoras[0].viva}.`)
console.log(`Hi my name is ${escritoras[1].nombre}, my fish name is ${escritoras[1].apellido}. I am ${escritoras[1].edad} years old a and working in: ${escritoras[1].profesion}, I am live ? : ${escritoras[1].viva}.`)
console.log(`Hi my name is ${escritoras[2].nombre}, my fish name is ${escritoras[2].apellido}. I am ${escritoras[2].edad} years old a and working in: ${escritoras[2].profesion}, I am live ? : ${escritoras[2].viva}.`)
console.log(`Hi my name is ${escritoras[3].nombre}, my fish name is ${escritoras[3].apellido}. I am ${escritoras[3].edad} years old a and working in: ${escritoras[3].profesion}, I am live ? : ${escritoras[3].viva}.`)
console.log(`Hi my name is ${escritoras[4].nombre}, my fish name is ${escritoras[4].apellido}. I am ${escritoras[4].edad} years old a and working in: ${escritoras[4].profesion}, I am live ? : ${escritoras[4].viva}.`)
```

O sea ya no sé qué hacer literal porque como dije todos van pero el último no me funciona, me da error con el nombre.

Comment: Tu array tiene 4 elementos, cuyos indices son 0 - 1 - 2 - 3, ahí ya tienes tus 4 elementos, escritoras[4] no existe

Comment: Los arrays empiezan en la posición 0, no en la 1...

Comment: Si te dice que no está definido es que no lo está por muy imposible que te parezca.

Answer (score 7):

Hola acabo de revisar tu código y a simple vista lo que pude detectar es que, vos dentro de tu objeto tienes declarado 4 elementos:

0. 'Virginia'
1. 'Zadie'
2. 'Jane'
3. 'Bell'

Y cuando consologueas por posición, al llegar a la posición [4], te dice `undefined` porque en la posición 4 no existe ningún elemento, ya que arrancas desde la posición [0], y cuando contamos arrancamos desde el 1, entonces está bien tu código, solo que estás haciendo un console.log() de más.

Espero haya sido de ayuda mi respuesta, traté de ser lo más claro posible !! :D